# Angular build throws error, unexpected token . in JSON

Tags: angular

Angular build shows the following error only on linux machine. When I use it on windows, it works completely fine. I can seem to debug the problem underneath. A little help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you storing any information inside your localStorage?
Try clearing localStorage and check it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I just solved it. It was a runtime exception left unhandled. :)